# Is there a good Modern English translation of Newton's "Philosophiæ Naturalis Principia Mathematica" available for free viewing or download?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, soft-question, specific-reference, history

I have found several nice versions available for purchase, but all of the free ones are either Latin, old English, or pixellated. I searched google and was only able to locate the free ones linked to from the Wikipedia page on [Philosophiæ Naturalis Principia Mathematica](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophi%C3%A6_Naturalis_Principia_Mathematica).

Comment: There is a book in the amazon http://www.amazon.com/Principia-Mathematical-Principles-Natural-Philosophy/dp/0520088174

Comment: Please note the word "free" in my question.

Comment: @user: I don't think that there *is* a Stack Exchange site for this kind of request. There is no guarantee that every question will find a home here. But the question isn't about physics. It's about finding a book, and a free one at that. The Chat is not very busy, but it would be better than posting a question because the rules are much looser there (almost non-existent).

Comment: Related question on Math.SE: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/860045/11127

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You overestimate the amount of evolution that the English language has undergone in the last 300 years. I recommend you the perfectly readable English translation by my great great grand uncle Motte, as revised by Cajori:

> http://books.google.com/books?id=ySYULc7VEwsC&printsec=frontcover&hl=en&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false

Let me just be a linguist for a while. ;-) Modern English has existed since 1550

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_english

when the Great Vowel Shift took place, so not only Motte's 1729 translation linked above is written in Modern English but Isaac Newton was speaking Modern English throughout his life, too. Of course, Newton would write in Latin.

Comment: Thankyou. I would be crazy to expect more and it still be free.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure why you say "more". I think that Motte's translation is still the best one. ... It's not hard to freely get the other translations as well but I am surely not going to promote the well-known methods publicly.

Comment: Here you have another free edition from 1900: http://books.google.com/books?id=tvcpV21I3HkC&printsec=frontcover&hl=cs&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false - This edition contains the first three sections of the first book, about 300 pages.

Comment: by "more" I mean that, while it is available for free viewing, it is not available for free download (that I am aware of). Also, a more recent revision of this work would doubtlessly ease the reading process. But I am being rather picky at this^^ I like it.

Comment: Dear @user2843, if you want to download the books from Google Books, just download the Google Books Downloader, http://www.softpedia.com/progDownload/Google-Book-Downloader-Download-112996.html ... Almost all these things are doable.

Answer (score 1):

The first American edition (New York, Daniel Adee, call number QA803.A4 1846), translated by Andrew Motte, is available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/) at

> https://archive.org/details/100878576.

It is available in ePub, Kindle, Daisy and DjVu (30.5 MB) formats, as well as for online viewing in a dedicated viewer.